# Explicity vs implicit first order euler to approximate $e^{\alpha x}, \alpha > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Hello for the function

$$
y(x) = e^{\alpha x} \Leftrightarrow y' = \alpha y, y(0)=1
$$

I wanted to evaluate the error of the two following iterations

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y_k = y_{k-1} + \alpha y_{k-1} \delta t \\
y_0 = 1
\end{array}
\right. \Rightarrow y_k = (1+\alpha \delta t)^k
$$

and

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y_k = y_{k-1} + \alpha y_{k}\delta t \\
y_0 = 1
\end{array}
\right. \Rightarrow (1 - \alpha \delta t)y_k = y_{k-1} \Rightarrow y_k = (1 - \alpha \delta t)^{-1} y_{k-1} \Rightarrow y_k = (1-\alpha \delta t)^{-k}
$$

Now I'd like to evaluate the the errors using

$$
y(k\delta t) = e^{\alpha k \delta t} = 1 + \alpha k \delta t + \alpha^2 \frac{k^2}{2} \delta t^2 + ...
$$

I can figure the taylor expansion of the first iteration (assuming $\delta t \rightarrow 0$), indeed I would get

$$
y_k = \sum_{l=0}^{k} \binom{k}{l} (\alpha \delta t)^l
$$

In such a case
$$
y(k\delta t) - y_k = O(\alpha \delta t)
$$

In the second iteration though I was expecting less error (asymptotically at least, i.e. something like $O(\alpha^2 \delta t^2)$), Taylor expansion I managed to get, not sure if this is correct

$$
y_k = \sum_{l=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\Gamma(1-k)}{\Gamma(1-k-l)\Gamma(l+1)} (-1)^l(\alpha \delta t)^l = 1 + \alpha k \delta t + \frac{k (k+1)}{2}\alpha^2\delta t^2 + ...
$$

however the entailed error in this case is the same, is there something I'm missing? or is what I've done correct?

Answer (score 1):

You get easier results by comparing the powers in question in the exponents, that is as arguments of an exponential function after applying the appropriate logarithms.
\begin{align}
(1+αδt)^k=\exp\left(k\ln(1+αδt)\right)
&=\exp\left(αkδt\left(1-\frac{αδt}2+\frac{(αδt)^2}3-\frac{(αδt)^3}4+...\right)\right)
\\&=\exp\left(αt_k-\frac{α^2}2t_kδt+...\right),
\\
(1-αδt)^{-k}=\exp\left(-k\ln(1-αδt)\right)
&=\exp\left(αkδt\left(1+\frac{αδt}2+\frac{(αδt)^2}3+\frac{(αδt)^3}4+...\right)\right)
\\&=\exp\left(αt_k+\frac{α^2}2t_kδt+...\right).
\end{align}
So you see, in both cases you get nearly the same first-order error, only with opposite signs.

Comment: Ah, I was expecting something better for the second, since it is an implicit method, I was wrong.

Comment: No, they are both first order and time-reverse to each other. Alternating explicit and implicit steps you get the midpoint method which is of second order.

Comment: So one method might be more convenient than the other only for stability reasons I suppose

Comment: Yes, but except for educational purposes you would almost always use higher order implicit methods, one- or multi-step.